Verify setup mock if it isn't executed
When I am making unit tests I like being a little explicit with them. For example, when I make the mock setups I like to verify if every one should be called or not. For example in this test case I am being very explicit with the verification times. So I would like to know if it is a good practice or I should omit it.
public class UserServiceTest
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task CreateAsync_Should_ReturnErrorFailure_WhenUserExists()
    {
        // Arrange
        CreateUserRequest request = new("Pepito", "Leon", "rleon", "example@email.com", "Pass123", RoleId: 1);
        User expected = new()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            FirstName = request.FirstName,
            LastName = request.LastName,
            Username = request.UserName,
            Email = request.Email,
            Password = request.Password,
            RoleId = request.RoleId,
            IsActive = true
        };
        Mock<IUserRepository> mockUserRepository = new();
        Mock<IUnitOfWork> mockUnitOfWork = new();
        Mock<IPasswordHasher<User>> mockPasswordHasher = new();

        string passExpected = new PasswordHasher<User>().HashPassword(expected, request.Password);
        
        mockPasswordHasher.Setup(provider => provider.HashPassword(It.IsAny<User>(), request.Password))
            .Returns(passExpected)
            .Verifiable(Times.Once());
        
        mockUserRepository
            .Setup(repo => repo.ExistAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(true)
            .Verifiable(Times.Once());
        
        mockUserRepository
            .Setup(repo => repo.CreateAsync(It.IsAny<User>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(It.IsAny<User>())
            .Verifiable(Times.Never()); // It should never be called
        
        mockUnitOfWork
            .Setup(unitOfWork => unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync(default))
            .ReturnsAsync(0) // 0 rows affected
            .Verifiable(Times.Never()); // It should never be called

        UserService userService = new(mockUserRepository.Object, mockUnitOfWork.Object, mockPasswordHasher.Object);

        // Act
        var result = await userService.Create(request);

        // Assert
        mockUserRepository.Verify();
        mockUnitOfWork.Verify();
        result
            .IsFailure
            .Should()
            .BeTrue();
        result
            .Error
            .Type
            .Should()
            .Be(ErrorType.Conflict);
    }

}

In this test case repo => repo.CrateAsync() should never be called, because it supposed if I have an error, that function shouldn't be executed.
        mockUnitOfWork
            .Setup(unitOfWork => unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync(default))
            .ReturnsAsync(0) // 0 rows affected
            .Verifiable(Times.Never()); // It should never be called

Here is the user service
public sealed class UserService(
    IUserRepository userRepository,
    IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
    IPasswordHasher<User> passwordHasher) : IUserService
{
    public async Task<Result<Guid>> Create(CreateUserRequest request)
    {
        bool checkUser = await userRepository.ExistAsync(request.Email);
        if (checkUser)
        {
            return Result
                .Failure<Guid>(Error.Conflict("User.AlreadyEmail", $"Email { request.Email } is already"));
        }
        User user = new()
        {
            FirstName = request.FirstName,
            LastName = request.LastName,
            Username = request.UserName,
            Email = request.Email,
            RoleId = request.RoleId
        };
        string passwordHashed = passwordHasher
            .HashPassword(user, request.Password);
        user.Password = passwordHashed; 
        User userCreated = await userRepository.CreateAsync(user);
        await unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
        return userCreated.Id;
    }
} 

Pd: I am starting with Unit Testing
Thoughts or advice is gratefully received...

Nothing wrong with asserting negative test scenarios. I often have Times.Never checks where I assert that the scenario should not have something persisted. Just be sure to keep in mind balancing value against effort. The more explicit test scenarios get the more breaking tests you will likely encounter as the solution evolves. However that really just reflects the potential cost of changes, whether addressing assumptions asserted in unit tests, or gambling on assumptions at runtime that aren't reflected in unit tests.

Instead of passing a test-double "mockPasswordHasher", you can pass the actual implementation itself if you prepare passExpected using actual implementation. It looks like over engineering to me.

The test-double which stands in for PasswordHasher dependency can return a Dummy for HashPassword method call since that value is not used.  mockPasswordHasher.Setup(provider => provider.HashPassword(It.IsAny<User>(), request.Password)) .Returns(It.IsAny<String>()).Verifiable(Times.Once());

@StevePy I got it. For obvious test cases, the time checks could be omitted. Otherwise, I would be over-engineering or increasing the cost of changes, right?
In my case public async Task CreateAsync_Should_ReturnErrorFailure_WhenUserExists() is obvious that I am not going to call to repo => repo.CrateAsync() method, because I am going to have an error.

@SivaSankaran Thanks for the suggestion. According to your suggestions, Which should I choose, the first one or second one?. I would like to follow the best practices.

For the password hasher, the step to construct the real hasher is unnecessary, just use a constant string. const string passwordExpected = "MySuperHashedPassword" The fact that it is or is not a hashed password is irrelevant to the code under test. You just want to assert whether the password hasher was called and provide your code under test with the dependency. Mocking the dependency is preferred to passing initialized real ones since real ones can end up having dependencies themselves. Mock at the top level. PasswordHasher should have tests of its own.

So, a good practice for making unit test will be mocking all dependencies to the code under test no matter how small they are, right?
